# How to suppress raw types warnings in generated Canonical Metadata classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I'm using the [Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel Generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#introduction) to generate metamodel classes for my `@Entity` model classes so I can use typesafe criteria queries.

Due to the use of Generics in some of my model clases, some of the generated metamodel classes cause compiler warnings about raw types.  The generated code seems to function just fine, but I want to suppress these inconsequential warnings in the generated code.

Is there anyway I can get the metamodel generator to either:

- add a `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` annotation to each of the generated metamodel classes?
- or add a `package-info.java` file to each metamodel package to which would contain the same annotation

Either solution would be acceptable.  Is either possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the last metamodel generator (1.2) you can add @SuppressWarnings("all") to the generated metamodel classes. You cannot specify the suppress type, but, as all the warnings are useless if you are not going to change the generated classes, it could suit your needs.

You must set a processor option with -AaddSuppressWarningsAnnotation=true, you can find the documentation here:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.2/reference/en-US/html/chapter-usage.html#d0e349

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for!  I will give it a shot tonight.

Comment: Awesome!  Just updated to 1.2 and tried it and it fixed all my generics warnings.